# Скопировать часть сообщения aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Есть ли способ скопировать сообщение, но изменить в нём какой-то параметр? Например я хочу изменить текст сообщения, которое отправил пользователь, а всё остальное оставить без изменений.
bot.copy_message() копирует всё сообщение по его айди, и изменить какой-то один параметр нельзя

Comment: Так используя метод можно достать параметр текста сообщения, вытащить его и сформировать как новое сообщение с этим текстом, какие в данном случае могут быть проблемы?

Comment: Проблема в том, что к сообщению может быть прикреплено много всего(медиа, локация, аудио и тд). Не знаю как написать функцию которая бы доставала текст и меняла его а остальное сообщение нет. Парсить сообщение в ручную и проверять есть ли там медиа, аудио, геолокация, документ и так далее не очень хотелось бы, поэтому и спрашиваю, нет ли ещё вариантов

Comment: Вообще первое что приходит в голову это скачать все компоненты данного сообщения, а затем прикрепить как новое сообщение